# Roots of unity of an odd degree number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, roots-of-unity

I want to show that a number field of odd degree contains only $2$ roots of unity. The only information I really have regarding this that I think is relevant is that the group of units $\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ of a number field $K$ is such that 
$$\mathcal{O}_K^\times \cong \mathbb{Z}^{r_1+r_2-1} \times G$$
where $(r_1,r_2)$ is the signature of K, and $G$ is the finite cyclic group consisting of the roots of unity that lie in $K$. Then I am reduced to showing that $G$ only consists of two elements.

I know that the degree of a number field $n=r_1+2r_2$, so an odd degree $n$ means that that value of $r_1$ must be odd also.

My problem is, I am not sure what that shows - or even if it is relevant! The only consequence of this then is that the parity of $r_1+r_2-1$ reflects the parity of $r_2$, and I am not really sure if that means anything for the size of $G$. However, I cannot think of any other information given that suggests anything in terms of $\mathcal{O}_K^\times$, $r_1+r_2-1$ or $G$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n):\mathbb{Q}]=\varphi(n)$ is even for all $n\geq 3$.

Comment: Could you please explain this further?

Comment: If $\zeta_n\in K$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)\subseteq K$. Now remember that $[K:F]=[K:L][L:F]$ for any fields $K\supseteq L\supseteq F$.

Comment: So then $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)][ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n):\mathbb{Q}]$ can only be odd for $n <3$. Is this correct? Do I then have to show that $n >1$? Or have I got the wrong end of the stick?

Comment: Every number field contains the roots of unity $1$ and $-1$ (these are $\zeta_1$ and $\zeta_2$). If $K\supseteq \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ for some $n\geq 3$, then $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ is even. Therefore, if $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ is odd, we cannot have $K\supseteq\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ for any $n\geq 3$. Thus, $K$ cannot contain any roots of unity other than $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

The intuition is that the number field embeds in $\Bbb R$, and so does its group of roots of unity, whose image is also the group of roots of unity inside the embedding. Since roots of unity lie on the unit circle, only two real possibilities $\pm 1$ arise.

**Details:** Suppose $n = [K: \Bbb Q]$ is odd, and let $G_K$ denote the cyclic group consisting of roots of unity in $K$. Using your notation, we have
$$n = r_1 + 2r_2$$
which forces $r_1 \ne 0$, in particular, $r_1 \ge 1$. So, there exists at least one real embedding $\sigma: K \hookrightarrow \Bbb C$. Now, $$K \cong \sigma(K) \subset \Bbb R$$
from which it follows that
$$G_K \cong G_{\sigma(K)} \subset \Bbb R$$
The only roots of unity in $\Bbb R$ are $\pm 1$, so $G_{\sigma(K)} = \{\pm 1\}$. Then, $G_K = \sigma^{-1}(\{\pm 1\}) = \{\pm 1\}$ and $$G_K \cong \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$$ as required.